# What approach can I use to repeatedly fetch a file via AJAX without the included JavaScript being reloaded and causing conflicts or errors?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a PHP file that I am reloading multiple times into a div with an AJAX call. The fetched PHP file links to an external JavaScript file. The first time I retrieve the file, it works fine. However, when I retrieve the page with the AJAX call for the second time, I'm getting errors that variables have already been declared, which means the script is trying to reload every time I call that file. I can't attach it to the base page because the initial page is different from the subsequent fetches. Any ideas on how I can attach a JS script to a file that I'm fetching multiple times without errors on conflicting variables?

Here's a simplified version of my original code:

```html
<head></head>
<body>

<div id='window-change'>
    <?php include('base_page.php'); ?>
</div>

<button id="submit-form">Get results</button>

<script src="script_for_base_page.js"></script>
</body>
```

I then have an event listener on my button that performs an AJAX call to insert a PHP file that replaces all of the content within the div when the submit form button is clicked. This is the function I attach to the event listener for the 'search results' button.

```js
function loadResults() {
  selectedFilters.forEach(obj => {
    var key = Object.keys(obj)[0];
    var value = obj[key];
    pageData[key] = value;    
  });

  $.ajax({
    url: "./ajax/result.php",
    data: {pageData},
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
      $("#window-change").html(data);
    }
  });
}
```

In the fetched `result.php` file, I have a script tag that loads all the associated JavaScript for that page. After the fetch, my page looks like this:

```html
<head></head>
<body>

<div id='window-change'>
    <button>Next page</button>

    <various html elements with inline javascript via php>

    <script src='./for-ajax-call.js'></script>
</div>

<script src="script_for_base_page.js"></script>
</body>
```

I now have at this point removed the 'search results' button and added a 'Next Page' button. This button reloads the same page with updated `pageData` object that I'm passing in to load the next segment of table data.

The function I'm using for `loadResults` is pretty much copied inline JavaScript style into my PHP file, and I'm reloading it in `nextPage`.

```js
function loadResult() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "./ajax/result.php",
    data: {
      pageData: pageDatas
    },
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
      $("#window-change").html(data);
    }
  });
}

function nextPage() {
  pageNumber++;
  localStorage.setItem('pageNumber', pageNumber)
  pageDatas['PAGE_SORT'] = localStorage.getItem('pageNumber')
  loadResult()
}
```

Notice now I'm fetching the same page over and over now just with updated body that I'm sending in with my GET request. However, after pressing the 'next page' button and loading the `result.php` page for a second time, the JavaScript script is reapplied, and I get errors that variables have already been declared, and I'm guessing additional event handlers are being added redundantly as well.

I can't add the script to the base file or else I get errors that I'm trying to work with HTML elements that don't exist yet.

Things I've tried:

1. Busting the cache by appending my script with a time signature:

```html
<script src="./js_scripts/categories.js?t=<?php echo time(); ?>"></script>
```

This didn't work, and there was no difference.

2. Adding the script from the base page that I'm loading the content into when the submit-form button is clicked.

```js
let scriptLoaded = false;

document.getElementById('submit-form').addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (scriptLoaded === false) {
    let script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = './script_for_base_page.js';
    script.id = 'myScript'; // Assign the id here
    setTimeout(() => {
      document.body.appendChild(script);
      scriptLoaded = true;
    }, 500);
  }
});
```

I don't get any errors the second time I load the page, but my JavaScript just does not work anymore, with no errors being shown to the console.

3. Attempted to wrap the entire JavaScript file inside a function, attach it to a window, and call it in the loaded file like such:

(In the JavaScript file)

```js
function loadCategoriesScript(){ All my JS code  }
window.loadCategoriesScript = loadCategoriesScript
```

Then attach the file and call the function on `result.php`:

```html
<script src="./script_for_base_page.js"></script>
<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    loadCategoriesScript();
  })
</script>
```

This was more of a Hail Mary because I'd never done it before and came across this strategy with desperate searching for a solution. Nothing happened with this, and no script loaded. Intentionally misspelling the file path caused an error, but not with misspelling the function name.

So PLEASE, for the love of everything, help me with this if you can. This bug has been eating away at me. I can't concentrate on anything else, and no matter how much research I do, I can't find a way to fix this seemingly trivial bug. Thank you for any help.

[Here is what the head looks like after dynamically adding the script the first time, the javascript works at this point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvIgL.png)

[Here's how it looks the second time the function provided is called. The head looks exactly the same, though the javascript does not work at this point and it doesn't give any errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpuvX.png)

[Example variables from the ajax script that is causing errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCFIv.png)

[Some more variables and event listeners from the ajax script that is causing errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2f13.png)

[Script from the base page script that is not causing errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UB5Jq.png)

[Another example from the base page script that is not causing errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exUKN.png)

Comment: The script you call with AJAX shouldn't return the entire HTML page, it should just return the HTML that should be put into the DIV. So it should leave out the JavaScript and `<head>` and `<body>` tags.

Comment: `I can't add the script to the base file or else I get errors that I'm trying to work with HTML elements that don't exist yet.`...it wasn't 100% clear which block of code is the one that gets reloaded repeatedly? But at a guess, adapting the code to use delegated event handlers would be likely to help with problems of elements not existing yet. And/or taking a more function-based approach. It's hard to be specific without actually seeing the problem, but refactoring the code is likely to the be the real solution rather than trying to find all sorts of workarounds to the loading process.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: Anyway, from those examples I'd say 1) really most of these scripts look like they should be replaced with some proper responsive design using HTML and CSS. 2) I still can't see why you keep reloading them. Put it all into a function (or maybe more than one function, if you need to run different bits at different times), and load it when the page is first loaded. Then, execute the functions whenever you need them to execute - e.g. after the AJAX is loaded, for example. That's how everyone else does it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for clarifying things in the comments. Here's my updated answer.

Based on your main issue, I suggest you set a flag to check if your JavaScript file was already loaded.

You can do something like this:

```
function loadResults() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "./ajax/result.php",
    data: { pageData },
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
      // Remove the script tag containing the external JavaScript file first
      data = data.replace(/<script.*?src=["'](.+?)["'].*?><\/script>/gi, "");

      $("#window-change").html(data);

      // Load the JavaScript file separately if it hasn't been loaded before
      if (!window.forAjaxCallLoaded) {
        var scriptElement = document.createElement('script');
        scriptElement.src = './for-ajax-call.js';

        scriptElement.onload = function() {
          // Set a flag to indicate that the script has been loaded
          window.forAjaxCallLoaded = true;
        };
        // This will append the <script> element to the <head> section of the document, triggering the loading and execution of the external JavaScript file.
        document.head.appendChild(scriptElement);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

In summary, this code checks whether the `forAjaxCallLoaded` flag is set in the global `window` object. If the flag is not set, it creates a new `<script>` element and sets its `src` attribute to the URL of the external JavaScript file `('./for-ajax-call.js')`. Then, it appends the `<script>` element to the `<head>` section of the document.

The `onload` event handler is set on the `<script>` element to listen for when the script has finished loading. When the script is successfully loaded, the event handler sets the `forAjaxCallLoaded` flag to `true`, indicating that the script has been loaded.

This way, the external JavaScript file will be loaded and run only once, ensuring it is not reloaded with subsequent AJAX requests.

Comment: The variable being reset isn't pageNumber, it's the first variable declared in my external javascript file. If I were to change that I just receive an error that the next variable declared is throwing an error. Is the solution to not declare any global variables in my script and put them all inside the function body? I just worry then I'm attaching multiple event listeners to the same elements over and over again. How could I clear out the variables/reset the scope? I'm not getting any errors pertaining to the local storage variables, only the variables in the external javascript file

Comment: We want to clarify things so that the people in stack overflow can help you better and be able to provide you more appropriate answers.
**First:** which block of code gets reloaded repeatedly? **2nd:** What specific JavaScript file do you need to attach to the file that you're fetching multiple times? **3rd:** Do you really need to reload the whole page? or you just need to update a specific part of the page? **4th:** Do you need the `<script src='./for-ajax-call.js'></script>` be inside the `#window-change` div?

Comment: 1) The entire external javascript file I'm attaching to the file that I'm fetching is being reloaded again. The first global variable I have on the script is throwing an error that it's already been declared. 2) The javascript relates to on click actions of adding options to a list amongst other things. It's quite a large script 3) I do need to reload all of the result.php page again, it's a grid list of options pertaining to chosen filter options and the "next" button loads the next hundred results. 4) I need It to be attached because it pertains to objects that don't exist in base page

Comment: So to be clear and precise, the `./for-ajax-call.js` is the JavaScript file that you need to be loaded inside the `results.php`. but everytime you run the ajax call from the `loadResult` function, this `./for-ajax-call.js` is being reloaded, which causes the variable inside this js file being redeclared. Is that right?

Comment: Yes that's exactly right. For example, if I redeclare the variable names with var, I don't get errors but all my event listeners duplicate for every page load

Comment: Thanks for clarifying things. I updated my answer. Hope this one helps.

Comment: I can't thank you enough for jumping in and helping me sort this out. It's really awesome of you. I was super hopeful that this would do the trick, but it seems like the script isn't getting re-hooked after the second load of results.php. That chunk of code in the "if (!window.forAjaxCallLoaded){ }" only seems to kick in the first time it's appended, and then the JavaScript goes MIA after I fetch results.php for the second time with no errors on the console

Comment: sure. no problem, glad to help. Hmm. okay. Can we confirm if the javascript is at the head tag on first reload and then on the second relaod, was it gone? can you add on your posted question the screenshot of your html from dev tools if the `<script src='./for-ajax-call.js></script>` exists inside the `<head>` tag. so give 2 screenshot.screenshot the first load if it exists in the head tag, then another screenshot on your second reload.

Comment: Can you also provide the simplest code you have inside your `for-ajax-call.js` and your `cript_for_base_page.js` where it shows at least some variables you declare and just some of the listeners you added.

Comment: Apologies for the late reply, crazy day at work. The first two images are of the head before and after the function you proposed. As far as I can tell, they are identical and both have categories.js (the script for the ajax call) loaded. The next two photos are from the ajax call script and the last two photos are from the base page script that is not causing any issues. Let me know if there's any additional information I can provide. Thanks again so much!

Answer (score -1):

Try calling the file fetching method on a cron jos, like every 5 seconds, ot utilize something like Signal R